# EEA family permit to UK (spouse EEA nation)

Tags: visas, uk, sweden, russian-citizens

I'm Russian, have a permanent residency in Sweden. My wife is Swedish. 
We're going together to the UK. Wonder if can I get a free of charge UK visa?

When we visited Norway from UK, they issued for me a free visa to Norway, as I'm married to EEA nation.

Can I get something like EEA family permit to UK for free?

I've read this 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Economic_Area_Family_Permit
https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/overview

and applied in two places.

https://visas-immigration.service.gov.uk

https://www.visa4uk.fco.gov.uk

In both places I have to pay 100 EUR + 63 EUR for going to the visa center. (payment online, before my appointment is even booked...)

Are there any options to get it free?

Comment: You are supposed to get it for free; perhaps you selected the wrong visa type.  My mother in law got an EEA family permit in Sarajevo; she did not have to pay for her biometric appointment, nor (of course) for the permit itself.

Comment: It's free.  The site is currently buggy wrt family permits, write to the Public Enquiry Office at Lunar House and get a paper application.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_House

Comment: Thx @phoog it took me a while, but I finally found where they hide it :)

Answer (score 7):

Not obvious, but right way:

1. Go here: https://www.gov.uk/family-permit (**Fees: An EEA family permit is free.**)
2. Then click "apply". redirects here
   https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/apply (**You must apply online for an EEA family permit**)
3. Click "apply online" redirects here: https://www.gov.uk/apply-uk-visa
4. Here you have two options

   - "apply using the new service" (Standard Visitor visa, Marriage Visitor visa, Permitted Paid Engagement visa) goes to https://visas-immigration.service.gov.uk/product/uk-visit-visa
   - "Apply on the Visa4UK" (**for all other visas**) goes to https://www.visa4uk.fco.gov.uk/account/register
5. Register on **Visa4UK**
6. Login and click "Apply for myself", fill the form.

There you will see a form element:

**Reason for Visit:** visit, study, work, settlement, transit, other, exempt

You have to choose **other**!

**Visa Type:** choose **EEA/Swedish family member**

**Visa Sub Type:** choose **Family member of an EEA Nation**

List of supporting documents for your application:
https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/261446/eea-family-permit.pdf

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was something like that but did not remember exactly because it was over a year and a half ago. Someone has recently had the same problem on [Expatriates.SE]; now all I have to do is find that question again so I can link to this answer.

Comment: The question is at http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/9516/2440.