# Freedom of movement for family of EU citizen - applying for a free visa

Tags: schengen

According to [this site](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/non-eu-family/index_en.htm):

> "Applying for a visa If your non-EU family members need an entry visa,
>   they should apply for one in advance from the consulate or embassy of
>   the country they wish to travel to. If they will be travelling
>   together with you, or joining you in another EU country, their
>   application should be processed quickly and free of charge:
>
> Countries which are members of the border-free Schengen area should
>   issue visas within 15 days, except in rare cases, when the authorities
>   should provide an explanation for their decision. All other countries
>   (Bulgaria, Croatia, Cyprus, Ireland, Romania, UK) should issues visas
>   as quickly as possible."

How does one do this? I am currently living in the UK. I want to travel to France with my family. I tried to contact the consulate. I was told TLS Contact deals with all their visa stuff. I don't see any way I can obtain a free visa from them.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by what your question is. You need to apply to the consulate of the country you're traveling to. Which part of the process is causing you a problem?

Comment: The standard application form allows you to indicate that you're applying as a family member, but different countries have different procedures and will require you to register this online before submitting the application. Details vary.  Which country are you submitting the application to?

Comment: Note that you have to be applying as an "EU-citizen" in the UK. This excludes British Nationals (even if they hold another EU citizenship)

Comment: @CMaster I don't think that's correct. Family members of British citizens are certainly family members of EU citizens for the purpose of traveling to another EU country.

Comment: @MJeffryes I was assuming that OP wanted to get a Family of EU citizen visa *for the UK*. You are correct that the question doesn't specify where the visa is for. Which probably means it needs editing to clarify.

Comment: @CMaster The last sentence of the question ("I am currently living in the UK") does not seem consistent with the proposition that the question is about applying for a visa to the UK.

Comment: @phoog I don't see why not. My understanding was that the OP wanted to apply for a visa for family members, not as them.

Comment: @CMaster Oh I see.  Yes, it could be that.  I had assumed it was someone in the UK wanting to travel to another EU country with a family member.  The question definitely needs to be clarified.  I've voted to close as unclear.  Lost1: I will remove that vote or vote to reopen if you can [edit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/138937/edit) the question.

Comment: "I tried to contact the consulate" - which consulate?  The French consulate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply directly to the French government through their [France-Visas website](https://france-visas.gouv.fr/en_US/web/france-visas/ai-je-besoin-d-un-visa). On the first page of the form select "Short-stay" visa. On the second page, select the box "Spouse of French or family member of an EU citizen or similar ?"
[image]

On the third page you will see that the visa will be issued for free. Above there is a list of supporting documentation you will be required to provide, but strictly speaking under EU law, [most of this is not required](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/non-eu-family/index_en.htm). You do not need to provide evidence for the purpose of your stay, health insurance, accomodation, funds, or profession. Only the relationship between the EU citizen and their family members (marriage, birth certificates etc.).

Comment: do you know how to do the same thing for a spouse of a French citizen residing in France who wants to visit the UK?

Comment: @Lost1 You should read [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/81645/eea-family-permit-to-uk-spouse-eea-nation/81659#81659), and if you still have queries, please ask a new question.

Comment: "Above there is a list of supporting documentation you will be required to provide, but strictly speaking under EU law, most of this is not required. You do not need to provide evidence for the purpose of your stay, health insurance, accomodation, funds, or profession. " -- but if you dont have this when you try to get a visa, i assume they would turn it down?

Comment: @Lost1 They ought not to. The form probably wasn’t designed with this visa in mind, and the visa will be processed if you leave the fields entry or with a note that it isn’t required for you to provide it. Of course, sometimes national governments break EU law. In this case, you can use solvit.eu to complain and get the decision corrected. But if you have the documentation in hand already you might prefer to go with the flow.

Comment: i followed the link you gave. It asked for a huge list of information just like other visitors.

Comment: @lost1 Yes, as I said it does ask for it, but under EU law, France is not supposed to ask for it.